Next.js app built with tauri does not show my 404 page
I have a next.js app with a file /app/not-found.tsx that works perfectly when using
cargo tauri dev

But when I compile the app with
cargo tauri build

or
cargo tauri build --debug

And navigate to a page that does not exist, I get rendered / (/app/page.tsx page) instead of /not-found but my url is still  my.app/something-thats-not-found
Thats is my not-found.tsx file:
import {
  NotFoundButton,
  NotFoundContainer,
  NotFoundInfo,
} from "./styles/style";

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <NotFoundContainer>
      <NotFoundInfo>
        <h1>Not Found!</h1>
        <span>
          |、
          <br />
          (˚ˎ 。7
          <br />
          |、˜〵
          <br />
          じしˍ,)ノ
        </span>
      </NotFoundInfo>
      <NotFoundButton href="/">Go to home</NotFoundButton>
    </NotFoundContainer>
  );
};

export default function NotFoundCatchAllPage() {
  return <NotFound />;
}

I tried using this with NotFoundCatchAllPage() and without, but neither of them are working
tauri.conf.json:
{
  "build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "yarn build",
    "beforeDevCommand": "yarn dev",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:3000",
    "distDir": "../out"
  },
  "package": {
    "productName": "scribble",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": false,
      "window": {
        "all": false,
        "close": true,
        "hide": true,
        "show": true,
        "maximize": true,
        "minimize": true,
        "unmaximize": true,
        "unminimize": true,
        "startDragging": true
      },
      "globalShortcut": {
        "all": true
      }
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "category": "DeveloperTool",
      "copyright": "",
      "deb": {
        "depends": []
      },
      "externalBin": [],
      "icon": [
        "icons/32x32.png",
        "icons/128x128.png",
        "icons/128x128@2x.png",
        "icons/icon.icns",
        "icons/icon.ico"
      ],
      "identifier": "com.scribble.dev",
      "longDescription": "",
      "macOS": {
        "entitlements": null,
        "exceptionDomain": "",
        "frameworks": [],
        "providerShortName": null,
        "signingIdentity": null
      },
      "resources": [],
      "shortDescription": "",
      "targets": "all",
      "windows": {
        "certificateThumbprint": null,
        "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
        "timestampUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "security": {
      "csp": null
    },
    "updater": {
      "active": false
    },
    "windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Scribble",
        "width": 800,
        "decorations": false
      }
    ]
  }
}

next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


NextJS relies on the 404 functionality in SSR mode.
However when you package NextJS with Tauri, it just uses next export to package generated HTML and JS/CSS files (frontend only).
So there's no NextJS (server) listening to the route changes.
An easy solution would be to check if the requested page exists, and if it doesn't then redirect to a page of your choice.
Oh, and do these checks in the client side in JS.

Can i have an example how to make it?

Sure, can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve with the 404 functionality?

for example, user will somehow be navigated to page that doesnt exist
function: function (router: AppRouterInstance) {
          router.push("/about");
 },

or to page with searchParams(id) that does not exist
/page?id=x

so what i want, in both cases is to throw user to not found page, using not-found.tsx(or whatever is needed to make this)

well, for '/about' page you already know if it exists or not, but for the dynamic path of page?id=x you can do the check of your id (I assume that's how you pull data) and navigate to the placeholder if data is not found)

but what if user somehow can visit any page? like /adsadasdsa or /bcvbcv
how to handle them?

Here's one idea: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12348
